# Getting Wrong Position in Listview OnItemClick after filter

Tags: android, listview, filter, position, android-adapter

This is my **Adapter Class** for ListView,

Need Help, I am getting original positions, after filtering the listview, instead positions of filtered result. Code is given below, kindly go through it,if any query kindly ask.

```
// This is my Adapter Class for ListView



        public class mAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

        ArrayList<MlaData> dats;
        public ArrayList<MlaData> filterList;
        enter code here
        CustomFilter filter;

        Context c;
        ImageLoader imageLoader;


        public mAdapter(Context ctx,ArrayList<MlaData> dats){
            this.c=ctx;
            this.dats=dats;
            this.filterList = dats;

        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return dats.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return dats.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            int itemID;

            // orig will be null only if we haven't filtered yet:
            if (filterList == null)
            {
                itemID = position;
            }
            else
            {
                itemID = dats.indexOf(dats.get(position));
            }
            return itemID;
        }
    @Override

     public Filter getFilter() {
            if(filter==null)
            {
                filter = new CustomFilter();
            }
            return filter;
        }



        class CustomFilter extends  Filter{

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if(constraint!=null && constraint.length()>0)
                {
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                    ArrayList<MlaData> filters = new ArrayList<MlaData>();


                    //Filtering

                    for(int i=0;i<filterList.size();i++)
                    {
                        if(filterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                            MlaData MlaDat = new MlaData(filterList.get(i).getName(),filterList.get(i).getImageUrl(),filterList.get(i).getArea(),filterList.get(i).getId(),filterList.get(i).getEmail());
                            filters.add(MlaDat);
                        }
                        results.count=filters.size();
                        results.values=filters;
                    }
                }else {
                    results.count=filterList.size();
                    results.values=filterList;
                }
                return results;
            }@Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                dats=(ArrayList<MlaData>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
```

**MainActivity.java
(Only The ListView OnClick Function)** :

```
        private ArrayList<MlaData> MlaDats = new ArrayList<MlaData>();
       private String MlaNameString, MlaImageString, MlaIdString, MlaEmailString, MlaAreaString;
         private   GridView listView;
          private  mAdapter adapt;
          private  SearchView sv;


         listView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.mldata);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        int posi = (int) adapt.getItemId(position);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Rajasthan_Mla.this, MainActivity.class);
                       // int pos = (int) adapt.getItemId(position);
                        String MLAID = MlaDats.get(posi).getId();
                        String MLANAME = MlaDats.get(posi).getName();
                        String MLAEMAIL = MlaDats.get(posi).getEmail();
                        String MLAIMAGE = MlaDats.get(posi).getImageUrl();
                        String MLAAREA=MlaDats.get(posi).getArea();

                        intent.putExtra("MLA_ID", MLAID);
                        intent.put

Extra("MLA_NAME", MLANAME);
                    intent.putExtra("MLA_EMAIL", MLAEMAIL);
                    intent.putExtra("MLA_IMAGE", MLAIMAGE);
                    intent.putExtra("MLA_AREA", MLAAREA);

                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Mukesh", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("MLAID", MLAID);
                    editor.putString("MLANAME",MLANAME);
                    editor.commit();

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

**DataModel Class** :

```
package com.wdm.mukku.wdm;


public class MlaData {
    private String name;
    private String imageUrl;
    private String area;
    private String email;
    private String id;

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.imageUrl = image;
    }

    public String getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(String area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public MlaData(String name,String image,String area,String id,String email) {
        this.name=name;
        this.imageUrl=image;
        this.area=area;
        this.id=id;
        this.email=email;

    }
    public MlaData() {


    }
}
```

Comment: You need to get the new position with parent.getAdapter().getItem(position); You need the reference to the adapter of the new filtered list instead of the listview

Comment: instead of doing hard work in implementing `BaseAdapter` you need some custom adapter like: `class Adapter extends` [MatchableArrayAdapter](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0)`<MlaData> { ...` and override its `onBind()` and `matches()` methods

Comment: and inside `onItemClick` just call `adapt.getItem(position)`

Comment: @pskink can you help me How to modify this code according to my code.

Comment: Sorry, but not able to modify those functions, can you provide me a sample code.Thank You

Comment: how to implement those two methods according to my code.

Comment: whats unclear? did you see MatchableArrayAdapter sources? did you check when those two methods are called? did you create the custom `class Adapter extends MatchableArrayAdapter<MlaData> {...`? did you do anything?

Comment: Yes I extended my adapter with given class:

Comment: I got those methods in my adapter class

Comment: Thank You for your help I don't know why I am not understanding how to implement this, if will be very helpful if you can provide me a sample code or sample project using this.

Comment: Ok Done, Thank You. Everything working fine but still getting value of original list items.

Comment: Now everything working fine, thank you soo much. Too easy to implement this class.

Comment: so what was so hard in overriding just two methods?

Comment: Nothing, it was really easy. Actually I got confused because I dindn't knew it will be that easy.BTW Thank You Again

Answer (score 1):

You can get filtered listview's position by

```
((ListView) parent).getAdapter().getItem(position)
```

Example
        private ArrayList MlaDats = new ArrayList();

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
            MlaData mModel = ((ListView) parent).getAdapter().getItem(position);
            String id = mModel.getId();
            Log.d(TAG,"id = "+id);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First change this

```
public mAdapter(Context ctx,ArrayList<MlaData> dats){
   this.c=ctx;
   this.dats=dats;
   // will create a new array instead of referencing to the same object
   this.filterList = new ArrayList<MlaData>(dats); 
}
```

Next don't modify `dats` anymore and only use the filtered list, so you will keep the original list and use that when you filter on something else.

So use this in your filter

```
        // temp array to store filtered data
        ArrayList<MlaData> filters = new ArrayList<MlaData>();
        // use original list to loop through and check for matches
        for (int i = 0; i < dats.size(); i++) {
            if (dats.get(i).getName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) {   
                MlaData MlaDat = new MlaData(dats.get(i).getName(), dats.get(i).getImageUrl(), dats.get(i).getArea(), dats.get(i).getId(), dats.get(i).getEmail());
                filters.add(MlaDat);
            }
        }
        results.count = filters.size();
        results.values = filters;
    } 
    else {
        results.count = dats.size();
        results.values = dats;
    }
    return results;
}
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
      // assign the filtered data to filterList
      filterList = (ArrayList<MlaData>)results.values;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And finally change your methods to use the filtered list

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return filterList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filterList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return ((MlaData)filterList.get(position)).getId();
}
```

When you clear the filter you should reset the `filterList` to the original data again

```
filterList = new ArrayList<MlaData>(dats);
```

Comment: Thanks For response, but now not searching properly, I am getting only top positions of the original postion.

Comment: What do you mean with top positions?

Comment: I mean I am not getting the desired item on search, only the item with position 0 is getting in listView after searching for anything

Comment: Try adding a Log in the for loop of the filter and see if the items are added

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Update your adapter's method `getItemId()` as below:

```
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }
```

**2.** Update ListView `onItemClick()` method as below:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            MlaData item = MlaDats.get(position);

            String MLAID = item.getId();
            String MLANAME = item.getName();
            String MLAEMAIL = item.getEmail();
            String MLAIMAGE = item.getImageUrl();
            String MLAAREA = item.getArea();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Rajasthan_Mla.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("MLA_ID", MLAID);
            intent.putExtra("MLA_NAME", MLANAME);
            intent.putExtra("MLA_EMAIL", MLAEMAIL);
            intent.putExtra("MLA_IMAGE", MLAIMAGE);
            intent.putExtra("MLA_AREA", MLAAREA);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Mukesh", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("MLAID", MLAID);
            editor.putString("MLANAME",MLANAME);
            editor.commit();

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```